# Send through object reference from Laravel Job (simple OOP?)

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass a newed up Model Object as a reference from a Laravel Job to the called Object and method. I need to new up the particular model in the Job because I need it in the Job's failed() method to update that model (and persist to database) as it functions as a log.

```
class ScrapeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $store;
    protected $scrape;

    public function __construct(Store $store)
    {
        $this->store = $store;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->scrape = new \App\Scrape; // This is the log object.

        // Here I call the SuperStoreScraper
        $class = '\App\Scraper\\' . $this->store->scraper;
        (new $class($this->store, $this->scrape))->scrape();
    }

    public function failed(\Exception $e)
    {
        // Update the Scrape object and persist to database.
        $data = $this->scrape->data; // here I get the error... ->data is not found?
        $data['exception'] = [ // this should work since I'm casting data to an array in the Model class.
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'file' => $e->getFile(),
            'line' => $e->getLine()
        ];
        $this->scrape->data = $data;
        $this->scrape->status = 'failed';
        $this->scrape->save();
    }
}

class SuperStoreScraper extends Scraper
{
    public function __construct(Store $store, Scrape &$scrape) {
        parent::__construct($store, $scrape);
    }

    public function scrape() {
        $this->start();
    }
}

abstract class Scraper
{    
    protected $store;
    protected $scrape;

    public function __construct(Store $store, Scrape &$scrape) {
        $this->store = $store;
        $this->scrape = &$scrape;
    }

    protected function start()
    {
        $this->scrape->fill([
            'data' => [
                'store' => $this->store->name,
                'scraper' => $this->store->scraper
            ],
            'status' => 'scraping'
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine. The newed up object is passed to both the SuperStoreScraper and the parent Scraper class (through the constructor), BUT when I persist it to the database in the Scraper object start() method, it doesn't reflect that up to the ScrapeJob (which newed up the Scrape object) and then I get an error in the Job's failed() method when trying to update the persisted object.

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in ...\app\Jobs\ScrapeJob.php:54
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the exact line of code that is giving you that error ?

Comment: `$this->scrape->data;` in the failed() method.

Comment: Try to move this line `$this->scrape = new \App\Scrape;` to the `__construct`.

Comment: That doesn't work at all since the Queued Job is serialized on __construct. It's actually run in handle() method.

Comment: You are right, I don't remember if it starts a new object or used the unserialized one to run the failed. I think that It is by any mean doing a new object or something like that, and you have setted `$this->scrape` only in handle. There is an error there... can you debug the stack trace with xDebug ?

Comment: Hmm. To be honest, Xdebug is out of my knowledge. I will research it and try to debug further. But to me the error I'm getting seems to be related to that the Scrape object is not passed as a reference and thus not updated in the Job. Since if I run the same code that is in the failed() method in the Job, in the Scraper class instead, everything works... "data" is found.

Comment: Remember that you are passing `Scrap` as reference, maybe it is destroying the object before `failed()` and then, you have no `data`.

Comment: That could be it. It doesn't say about anything like that in the Laravel docs. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs). I really don't know, I'm stuck. I can't figure out another way to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the whole Job class is newed up once the failed() method is running. If I move the `$this->scrape = new \App\Scrape;` to the `__constructor` of the job. And remove the `SerializesModels` trait. I can see that everything _kind of_ works. But **two** Scrape instances are created. One when handle() is ran, and another one on failed().

Comment: I thought so, is there a problem with double instantiation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have *kind of* solved my issue now.

I've moved the \App\Scrape instantiation to the Job's __constructor, but also persist it to the database, like this:

```
protected $scrape;

public function __construct(Store $store)
{
    $this->store = $store;
    $this->scrape = \App\Scrape::create(['status' => 'queued']);
}
```

This works, I can access the Scrape model from both the Scraper and the Job's failed() method, **BUT**, if I have multiple tries on the Job I'd like to create new Scrape instantiations for each try. Right now the same Scrape instance (same id) is just updated with each Job retry.